# VBA/SQL iterate through query permutations until record is returned

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an Access database created that consists of a single table of user-created routing rules that will decide which trucker should be used when an order is placed.  At a minimum, a rule must have a DEST_ST, but the other four fields can be left blank to be as broad or specific as necessary (a blank would be synonymous with "ALL"):

```
DEST_ST      PLNT      PKNG_TYPE      MODEL      DEALER      TRUCKER
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  PA          1         PALLET                     25       SMITH BROS
  PA          1                                              CONOVER
  PA                                                         IDLEWILD
```

The intention is that for a given order, I want to return the most specific rule that is applicable.  For example, the following order would be assigned to CONOVER:

```
DEST_ST      PLNT      PKNG_TYPE      MODEL      DEALER
-------------------------------------------------------
  PA          1          RACK          4AL         25
```

While this order would be assigned to SMITH BROS:

```
DEST_ST      PLNT      PKNG_TYPE      MODEL      DEALER
-------------------------------------------------------
  PA          1         PALLET         5AL         25
```

And lastly this order would be assigned to IDLEWILD:

```
DEST_ST      PLNT      PKNG_TYPE      MODEL      DEALER
-------------------------------------------------------
  PA          2         PALLET         5AL         25
```

Conceptually, my solution for this is to run up to 16 SQL queries (one for each permutation) in a prioritized order until a record is returned:

```
   DEST_ST   PLNT   PKNG_TYPE   MODEL   DEALER
   -------------------------------------------
1.  MATCH    MATCH     MATCH     MATCH   MATCH
2.  MATCH    MATCH     MATCH     MATCH
3.  MATCH    MATCH     MATCH             MATCH
4.  MATCH    MATCH     MATCH
5.  MATCH    MATCH               MATCH   MATCH
6.  MATCH    MATCH               MATCH
7.  MATCH    MATCH                       MATCH
8.  MATCH    MATCH
9.  MATCH              MATCH     MATCH   MATCH
10. MATCH              MATCH     MATCH
11. MATCH              MATCH             MATCH
12. MATCH              MATCH
13. MATCH                        MATCH   MATCH
14. MATCH                        MATCH
15. MATCH                                MATCH
16. MATCH
```

Is there a straightforward way of implementing this in VBA given my proposed solution or should I be approaching this completely differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is using a temporary table with each trucker and a count of how many rules they match.

```
CREATE TABLE tblRuleMatchCount
    (TRUCKER VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    MATCH_COUNT INT)

INSERT INTO tblRuleMatchCount (TRUCKER, MATCH_COUNT)
SELECT TRUCKER, 0 FROM tblRoutingRules
```

Then when you want to calculate which rules match, you would first reset all MATCH_COUNTs to 0, and then use a query like this for each criteria.

```
UPDATE tblRuleMatchCount
INNER JOIN tblRoutingRules
ON tblRuleMatchCount.TRUCKER = tblRoutingRules.TRUCKER
SET MATCH_COUNT = MATCH_COUNT + 1
WHERE DEST_ST = pDestSt
```

Notice how this query is parameterized on DEST_ST. You would call each criteria query with the information from the order, then you would select the trucker with the maximum match count.

```
SELECT TOP 1 TRUCKER FROM tblRuleMatchCount
ORDER BY MATCH_COUNT DESC
```

The drawback to this approach is that you would want this table to be in a user-specific front-end database (or temporary database). You're going to be updating several rows every time you calculate a match, so you wouldn't want to put the table in the shared back-end database. Also, if you put it in the back end database, you would need to wrap the entire operation in a transaction.

Comment: This is a good idea for a solution, but I think it can be done with queries instead of writing the data to a temp table.  Either that or change the temp table name to include the user's ID or the current time or something else that might make it unique, so that more than one person can run it simultaneously.

Comment: Your solution ended up working perfectly so thanks for that. The limitations mentioned by you and Johnny Bones should not be an issue. I was mainly trying to patch together something for our small team to see if it is useful and to work out the kinks in the process.  Thanks again!